# Before and After javascript needs to be responsive

Tags: javascript

I have added a before and after javascript to my website and it works great on my desktop/laptop but does not appear correctly on smaller screens. The site is [www.joesautobodytractor.com/before-after-photos.html](https://www.joesautobodytractor.com/before-after-photos.html). It's probably an easy fix to make the photos/script responsive. I'm just not seeing it. Any help is appreciated.

The script is from Dynamic Drive but here is the actual script CSS:

```
div.beforeandafter {
    /* main container */
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: block;
    height: 375px;
    /* default height of main container */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    /* default width of main container */
}

div.beforeandafter img {
    max-width: none !important;
}

div.before,
div.after {
    /* before and after DIVs within main container */
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    /* CSS transition. Actual duration set inside script 
    (options.revealduration) */
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

div.after {
    z-index: 1;
    /* z-index of after div should be smaller than before's */
}

div.drag {
    /* main div used for separating and dragging between before and after slides */
    background: white;
    cursor: col-resize;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
    /* transition. 0.4s sets duration of drag fade in time */
    width: 2px;
    /* width of drag bar separator */
    z-index: 1001;
}

div.drag div.draghandle {
    /* handle bar within drag interface */
    background: darkred;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
    background: rgb(169, 3, 41);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1)), color-stop(44%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019', GradientType=1);
    height: 20%;
    /* height of drag handle */
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16px;
    /* width of drag handle */
}

div.before span.caption,
div.after span.caption {
    /* CAS to syle SPAN caption. Optional */
    background: black;
    bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font: bold 12px Germand;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    width: 90px;
}

div.before span.caption {
    left: 10px;
    right: auto;
}

div.before span.caption a,
div.after span.caption a {
    color: lightyellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just target the container, for small screens, something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  section {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
}
```